# How do I render results after I make an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a tinder clone for fun and learning and am trying to render the matches for a person. This is my first day with react native so please excuse my learning. I make an API call:

```js
function GetUser(){
    return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        alert(responseJson.matches[1].id + "=>" + responseJson.matches[1].name + "=>" +responseJson.matches[1].profilePic);
        return responseJson.matches;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```

Everything is fine as I see the data in my alert. When I try to use the results, then nothing renders:

```js
renderNewMatches() {
    GetUser().then((matches)=>{
        return (
          <View style={styles.new_matches_container}>
            <Text style={styles.new_matches_title_style}>New Matches</Text>
            <View style={styles.matches_container}>
              {matches.map((person) => {
                return (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    key={person.id}
                    style={styles.person_container}
                    onPress={() => this.pushToScreen('ChatDetail', { data: person } )}
                  >
                    <Image source={{uri: person.profilePic}} style={styles.person_image_style}/>
                    <Text style={styles.person_name_style}>{person.name}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity >
                );
              })}
            </View>
          </View>
        )
    });
  }
```

Funny thing is that if I hard code the data as

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"bob",
      "profilePic":"https://..."
   }
]
```

and skip the API call then it renders with that hard coded data.

Comment: Try to search for setState or useState or redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this method to render something then you can't use a promise.

The method **itself** needs to return an element. Even if you return the promise you're currently using that resolves to your element it will error.

You're best off using a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist). Make the flatlist data prop an array in your component's state, and then update the state with `setState` when you've got new matches. The flatlist will then re-render to reflect the change in state. Hope that makes sense!

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class NewMatches extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      matches: [] // <-- this will hold your matches. When you update with setState, the page will re-render
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    GetUser()
      .then(newMatches => this.setState({ matches: newMatches })) // <-- newMatches should be an array of objects. After your ajax call you will update your state like this
      .catch(err => console.warn(err));
  }

  render() {
    return ( // <-- the method MUST return an element directly
      <View style={styles.new_matches_container}>
        <Text style={styles.new_matches_title_style}>New Matches</Text>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={item => item.id} // <-- take `id` property from each person and use it as the key
          contentContainerStyle={styles.matches_container} // <-- the way to style a flatlist, instead of `style`
          data={this.state.matches} // <-- the array in your state that flatlist will map over
          renderItem={({ item: person }) => { // take the `item` property from `item` (bit confusing!) and rename it to `person`
            return ( // <-- for each 'person' object in your state array, return the following element
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.person_container}
                onPress={() => this.pushToScreen('ChatDetail', { data: person })}
              >
                <Image source={{ uri: person.profilePic }} style={styles.person_image_style} />
                <Text style={styles.person_name_style}>{person.name}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't make much since. My first day with react. Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: I've added some code to help illustrate. Let me know if you have questions :)

Comment: @James, Is it possible to use await instead of promises?

Comment: @MilanKarunarathne You could do that, yes (though just so you know, async/await **IS** returning a promise. As soon as you add `async` in front of a function that function **returns** a promise to whatever calls it). So you could write `async componentDidMount() {...}` and `const newMatches = await GetUser()` etc. But I think this block is small enough that it's pretty clean already. I generally don't think async/await adds much. It can help if you start getting lots of nested promises, but at that stage you can also just break each promise into its own separate function anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### React/React-Native

You cannot use Promise here. So when your page loads, this componentDidMount() method will execute and this will fetch data from getUser method. componentDidMount() is just like using useEffect() in functional based component. Please Chaange your return to your need in getUser() method.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
      }
    GetUser(){
        return [{"id":1,"name":"bob","profilePic":"https://..."}];
    }
    state
    componentDidMount()
      {
           const data = this.GetUser();
           this.setState(...data);
      }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.name}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to start and close curly bracket of methods renderNewMatches()  and i have updated my code. please vote me up

Comment: I get `can't find variable: componentDidMount`. When I import it `import React, { Component }, { componentDidMount } from 'react';` it leads to another unexpected token error

Comment: I haved updated the code and its completely works for me. Please Update return method of getUser() according to your need